# many cache<T> or many adaptor<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, enterprise-library

I have an architecture question:

In my application we have 4 DataModels.

We want to save each of them in the cache.

The question is which way is better:

a. Creating many implementations of `ICache<T>`
with `set<T>` and `get<T>`

b. Creating many implementations of  `ICacheAdaptor<T>`.
The Adaptors are responsible for casting `object to different types`
and only one cache with `object set` and `get(object)`

I think I don't I need different settings in the `web.config` for each cache.

What would you suggest?

Comment: Are you asking this in the context of using Enterprise Library Caching Application Block (as per the tags)?

Comment: currently I'm using Enterprise Library Caching. But my loose coupling design will enable me to change it anytime. My q is architectual.